# How do I connect to a remote heroku db?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, heroku, heroku-postgres

Don't have much experience with Heroku.  I have the app/db name, username, password, and I have permission to access, but I'm not sure how to connect to it or configure Heroku to keep track of it, like the db's on my other apps.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's been a while since I've done this so you might need to check that the format hasn't changed but remote databases in heroku are done through environment variables.

Try something like:

```
heroku config:add DATABASE_URL=mysql://username:password@serveraddress:3306/databasename
```

Comment: Is the 3306 in this situation the port number? And if adapter: postgresql, then do I use that instead of mysql?

Comment: I think `pg` https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#external-connections-ingress

Comment: I execute this command and when I type heroku pg the db doesn't show up in the list